# Обновить много строк одновременно

Tags: sql, sqlite

Здравствуйте. Есть таблица SQLite:

```
id | playername | minutes
```

Каждую минуту нужно у заданых `playername` добавить +1 к `minutes`.

Такой код не работает:

```
Player[] players = Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers();
if(players.length == 0) return;
int iter = 0;
String query = "UPDATE timetop SET minutes=minutes+1 WHERE playername = ";
for(Player p : players) {
    System.out.println("iter: " + iter + ". length: " + players.length);
    query = query + "'" + p.getName() + "'";
    if(iter+1 == players.length) query = query + ";";
    else query = query + ", ";
    iter++;
}
System.out.println("QUERY: " + query);
db.execute(query);
```

А если точнее то он ругается на непонятный оператор ','.

Comment: У вас есть вывод получаемого запроса. Добавив его в текст, вы улучшите качество вопроса

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю, ошибка в том, что вы используете условие `where playername = ...` вместо условия `where playername in (...)`.

Сейчас ваш запрос выглядит так:

```
UPDATE timetop SET minutes=minutes+1 WHERE playername = 'pl1', 'pl2';
```

Нужно сформировать запрос вида:

```
UPDATE timetop SET minutes=minutes+1 WHERE playername IN ('pl1', 'pl2');
```

---

Также есть некоторое замечание по поводу того, что для составления строки из частей лучше использовать `StringBuilder` вместо простой конкатенации строк.

```
StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder(
    "UPDATE timetop SET minutes=minutes+1 WHERE playername = ");
for (...) {
    query.append(...);
}
db.execute(query.toString());
```

Comment: Спасибо! Я искал этот синтаксис но не нашел. Видимо плохо искал. Спасибо еще раз.

Comment: @AlexWells, а ещё есть мнение, что лучше в БД хранить статические значения, вроде времени открытия сессии, и вычислять при необходимости те значения, которые часто меняются, путём вычитания из текущего времени этого самого статического значения.